# Entropy change in heated block

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

The header of the problem asks us to calculate the entropy change $\Delta S$ (in the universe) when heating an iron block from $T_1$ to $T_2$, knowing its heat capacity $C_V$. Is it possible to determine $\Delta S$ with just this information?

I have read in other threads ([e.g.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112088/calculating-entropy-change-reversible-vs-irreversible-process)) that we should just be concerned about the initial and final states and just find a reversible process that takes us from the initial to the final state, and since $S$ is a state variable, $\Delta S$ should be the same.

So simply
$$\Delta S_{sys}=\int_{T_1}^{T_2}\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}, dQ_{rev}=C_pdT\implies \Delta S_{sys}=C_p ln(T_2/T_1).$$

However, I believe we should also consider the surroundings (if we do not, please help me understand why), so that

$$\Delta S_{univ}=\Delta S_{surr}+\Delta S_{sys},$$
and $\Delta S_{sys}$ is what we just calculated. If we account for the surrounding, knowing that it must provide the heat needed to heat the block $Q=C_p(T_2-T_1)$ we find that the entropy will depend on the path chosen. For example, if we put the iron block in contact with a reservoir at $T_2$, then

$$\Delta S_{surr}=\frac{Q'}{T_2}=\frac{-C_p(T_2-T_1)}{T_2}.$$

If instead, we use two different reservoirs at $\frac{T1+T2}{2}$ and $T2$, then

$$\Delta S_{surr}=C_p(-\frac{T_f-T_i}{T_f}\bigg\rvert_{T_1\rightarrow(T_1+T_2)/2}-\frac{T_f-T_i}{T_f}\bigg\rvert_{(T_1+T_2)/2\rightarrow T_2}).$$

Then it seems that for different processes, we have different entropy changes.

My questions then are:

1- Taking the question as is, should we take into account the entropy change in the surroundings?

2- If we must account for the surroundings, why is the entropy process-dependant, if it is a state variable? This cannot be, so the only option is that either the problem is missing information (about how the block is heated), or the method is wrong.

3- If it is missing information, what should that information look like?

If I had to answer my own questions I would say (but I am not very confident):

1- Yes, you should account for the surroundings.

2- The problem is missing necessary information about the state of the surroundings.

3- The problem should read something like "(...) using a reservoir at temperature $T$ (...)". Although I have seen problems that are solved without these specifications.

Apologies for the question on entropy, as I know it has been discussed extensively in this forum, but the truth is that after reading through all the posts I could see I still have doubts.

Thanks!

Comment: "*If we must account for the surroundings, why is the entropy process-dependant, if it is a state variable? This cannot be, so the only option is that either the problem is missing information, or the method is wrong.*" Please edit your question to clarify where you think the contradiction lies. In your various examples, you end up with one substantially cooled reservoir in the rest of the universe, or a few minimally cooled reservoirs, or an infinite number of unchanged reservoirs. These are all different states—there's no reason to expect the change in entropy, a state variable, to match.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I thought: the question should provide some information about how the block is heated. If the answer is just that I will probably delete the question. Thank you.

Comment: In all the scenarios you have described, the system always ends up in the same final state, and its change in entropy is always the same.  But the final states of the surroundings are not the same, depending on the temperature of each reservoir and how much heat it has received.  So the changes in entropy of the surroundings is different in the various cases.  I don't see any contradiction here.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to apologize here. It is not a stupid question for all I can tell. I believe it even has a technological implementation in counter-flow heat exchangers, which are quite efficient in exchanging heat between two different working fluids while minimizing the total entropy production in the universe. My TD is very rusty, though, so someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ChetMiller First of all thank you for all your contributions to thermodynamics questions on this forum; every answer you gave was insightful. To clarify, there is not supposed to be a contradiction, just a question of whether it is possible to provide a definite answer to the total entropy change with the information given, which we cannot since we must know how the block is heated to know how the surroundings are affected.

Comment: @FlatterMann I will wait until tomorrow to see what people comment and then decide if I should delete it. Entropy can be a confusing concept, and I would like the information available online not to be confusing too. Might be interesting if you do not know, in the limit of an infinite number of intermediate reservoirs in the example explained in the question, it comes out that the process is reversible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entropy change in the universe is
$$
   S_\text{gen} = \Delta S_\text{sys} + \Delta S_\text{sur} 
$$
Assuming constant-pressure heating of the block of iron, the entropy change of the system is
$$
   \Delta S_\text{sys} = C_P \ln\frac{T_2}{T_1}
$$
(We need the $C_P$, not the $C_V$, but to a good approximation $C_P\approx C_V$ for solids and liquids).

For the surroundings we need to make an assumption. In the absence of any detail the standard assumption is to take the surroundings to be a bath  at $T_\text{bath} = T_2$, since we need a heat source that is at least that hot to bring the iron to that temperature. Therefore,
$$
   \Delta S_\text{sur} = -\frac{Q}{T_2}
$$
Finally for the entropy generation we have
$$
   S_\text{gen} = C_P \ln\frac{T_2}{T_1}-\frac{Q}{T_2}
$$
If the heat source is at $T>T_2$ the entropy generation will be even higher, as we can tell from the last equation. Also, if the source is not a bath but, say hotter piece of iron that goes from $T'_1$ to $T'_2$ (with $T'_2>T_2$), the entropy generation is again higher. Therefore, the result is the most conservative estimate we can give of the entropy generation.